# The set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ contains closed intervals only?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ contains closed intervals only? After all, the set of irrational numbers in any interval is uncountable and dense in the set of real numbers, so it has a measure of the interval itself. Can I develop a strict subset of set of the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ with the difference of their measures less than an epsilon?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Your post seems to be asking two or three different things at the same time and the ideas don't seem immediately related. Closure is a topological notion whereas measures are a measure theoretic notion and these two aren't immediately related in your case. Can you please refine your question so that we can best address it for you?

Comment: What do you mean by closed here? Closed in the topological sense means every sequence in your set with limit in $[0,1]$ must have this limit in your set. But we can construct a sequence of irrationals in $[0,1]$ that converges say to $0$; which is not irrational.

Comment: Your last question does not bear on the definition of closed.  In the reals, closed means that every limit of points in the set is in the set.  Can you find a rational that is the limit of a series of irrationals?

Comment: I mean a set containing only closed intervals like [2.1,2.2]. However, the set of irrational numbers is dense so this confuses me.

Comment: So, you are asking whether there exists a zero measure subset of the irrationals between 0 and 1 expressible as the union of some number of closed intervals?

Comment: Yes, I am asking exactly that.

Comment: In which case, your original concern is quite valid- there are both no zero measure closed intervals on the real line, and no closed intervals which are subsets of the irrationals, because the rationals are dense in R. Thus, not only can you not pick a collection of closed intervals in the irrationals, if you were to do so, their union would have strictly positive measure.

Comment: In a twisted form, yes: accepting $[a,a] = \{a\}$ as interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed up several different ideas here. Firstly, the set of irrattionals in $[0,1]$ is not closed- in fact, the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, so there are many missing limit points. However, as you note, the interval $I$ does have positive measure- in fact, given any set of zero measure $M$, in particular for any countable collection (like the rationals), the measure of $I-M$ is the same as the measure of $I$. So, if you take any countable collection, say the set of all rationals multiplied by some irrational number, and subtract that set from the irrationals between 0 and 1, the measure will still be the same.

Edit-

In response the the clarified question (from the comment above), there are both no zero measure closed intervals on the real line, and no closed intervals which are subsets of the irrationals, because the rationals are dense in R. Thus, not only can you not pick a collection of closed intervals in the irrationals, if you were to do so, their union would have strictly positive measure.

Comment: Micah, I have modified my question. I mean does set of irrational numbers consist of only closed intervals.

Answer (score 1):

For the new question about intervals, the fact that the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$ says that every interval includes at least one (in fact countably infinitely many) rationals, so the irrationals do not include any interval.  You seem to be assuming that any set of full measure, which the irrationals are, must include the whole interval, but that is not correct and the irrationals are an excellent example.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=\{x\,:\, x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\}$ and let $\overline{I}$ be the closure of $I$.

If $I$ were expressible as a union of closed intervals, then $I$ would be closed and $\overline{I}=I$.

But we know that $I$ is dense in $[0,1]$ thus $\overline{I}=[0,1]\ne I$.